# Django multiple AJAX queries for images

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I made a button the user can click and it makes a AJAX GET request to the backend class Image. The response is the image url. I paste the url into a image tag and display it on the template

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField()
```

views.py
def ajax(request):
from django.http import JsonResponse

```
if request.is_ajax():
    image = request.FILES.get('data')
    aaa = Image.objects.get(id=1)
    aaa = str(aaa.img.url)
    return JsonResponse({'image_query': aaa}, status=200)

return render(request, 'components/ajax.html')
```

AJAX (template)

```
<button id="getData" class="btn btn-success">Get</button>
<div id="seconds"></div>

...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#getData').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    data: $(this).text()
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#seconds').append('<img src="' + response.image_query + '" width="300">')
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Everything works fine and the image is rendered to the template! Now I dont want to query the image with ID=1, I want all images to be fetched to the template.
I tried to do by adding a for loop into the views.py but it only returns the first element.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    image = request.FILES.get('data')
    for i in range(1, 5):
        aaa = Image.objects.get(id=i)
        aaa = str(aaa.img.url)
        return JsonResponse({'image_query': aaa}, status=200)
```

I don't know what to modify that it will query every image in the DB. Does someone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning the only first element because you are returning inside the `for` loop, instead put the `return` 1 indent back, and put all of the urls in array.

```
... # code you have above
images = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    aaa = Image.objects.get(id=i)
    images.append(aaa.img.url)) # append the url to the list
return JsonResponse({'images': images}, status=200) # 1 indent back
```

as a result you'll have to change your javascript code like this.

```
const success = (response) => {
    // Loop through each of the links
    for (let i=0; i < response.image_query.length; i++) {
        $('#seconds').append('<img src="' + response.image_query[i] + '" width="300">')
    }
}

// ... Other code

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        data: $(this).text()
    },
    success: success,
});
```

Also be carefull with `$('#seconds').append('<img src="' + response.image_query + '" width="300">')`, appending raw html could cause an **XSS** attack, if you are not completely sure that `response.image_query` is safe do not do this. (Since it is a url it should be escaped)

Comment: If I do so i'll only get the last element of the for loop so in this case only the element with id=5

Comment: yes, that was my bad, updated the anwser.

Comment: A okay you put it in a list, THANKS that worked for me :)